# Rails / Rename or move files

Tags: ruby, file, move, rename

I found a couple of different ways to move a file with ROR, but I couldnt get it to work, whats the best and simplest way to move or rename a file ?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the standard method:

```
File.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

Or you can use FileUtils which offers additional functionality.

Comment: works great, it moves the file, but keeps giving me this error:  Errno::ENOENT

Comment: <code>File.rename 'public/objects/file.png','public/objects/db/file.png'</code>

Comment: You can just use backticks for code quoting, by the way. What might be the problem is either the originating file or the destination directory does not exist. `public/objects/db` needs to be created before you move it.

Comment: Strange.. now it works.. I used the variable instead of a static input, since the script was run several times it failed on second attempt since it wasen't there... both folders was created beforehand..